# Java list map function not working

Tags: java, arraylist, java-stream

```
myList
.stream()
.map((question) -> {                    
     question.setQuestionId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
     return question;
});
```

Following java code is not getting into the map function. Can someone please point me to what am I doing fundamentally wrong here? myList is an ArrayList with some elements in it.

Comment: You didn’t tell it to do anything with the mapped value.

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the documentation for [`java.util.stream.Stream.map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-), you'll see that this method returns a new stream. If you need to keep your original list, use this method and store the results in a new list:

```
List<...> newList = myList
                     .stream()
                     .map(question -> {                    
                       question.setQuestionId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
                       return question;
                     })
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you just need to modify your original list, since `List` implements [Iterable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html), you can use [java.lang.Iterable.forEach](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-):

```
myList.forEach(question -> question.setQuestionId(UUID.randomUUID().toString()));
```

Answer (score 4):

Streams in Java are *lazy*. It means that no transformation, such as `map`, will be executed until its results is requested. The usual way to request the result of the whole stream is to use some terminal operation, such as `forEach` or `collect`. Without terminal operation nothing gets executed.